# On Windows 10, can programs read saved wifi passwords behind my back?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, passwords

I don’t see any settings for giving or denying access to saved wifi passwords. I know if the user goes into network properties, wifi passwords are viewable as plain text from there, but this is different from a third-party program reading wifi passwords without the user’s knowledge or consent.
Does windows allow programs that are not part of the system to read saved wifi passwords without the user’s knowledge or permission?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done.

At an Admin Command Prompt, type:

Command Prompt: netsh wlan show profile name="Profile Name"   key=clear to see password

and you can get the WiFi password.

It depends on the attacking program, but the information is there if the program has the capacity.

So, probably you are OK, but be careful what is installed.

I have tested this here on Windows 10 Pro. It also works on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I could figure out if a program is doing something like this?

Comment: You would need to look through Programs and Features to see if there is a program unknown to you and in the list of installed programs. I do not think this is likely but (a) you asked if it was possible (yes) and (b) you would need to give someone access to your computer.

Comment: You mean it does require admin privilege, right?

Comment: It depends on what the rogue program is doing. Most individuals run as Admin, so this too is possible. It is not likely, but possible.

Comment: Thank you. If I’m logged in on an admin account, but run programs normally (not running from “as administrator” in the right-click menu), the programs should not have admin access to anything, should they?

Comment: I answered your question as posed, but now consider security:  Log off when not using your computer. Use a screen saver / lock to ensure this. The more security you take about what you install and who you give access, the safer you are.

Comment: @AskerofCuriousQuestions - The stored WiFi password isn't typically consider something that has to be protected, so the store profile, doesn't require elevated permissions to read the registry keys.  You have to keep in mind, physical access to the location with the access point would have to be required.  It seems you have multiple questions, and your primary question, has already been answered.

Comment: Thank you. I just need a way to find out of a program on my computer is reading wifi passwords. Is there a way of doing so?

Comment: It is hard to know what a rogue program can possibly do. If nothing in Programs and Features is strange in there, you probably are OK.  As @ramhound has noted you are asking multiple questions, but it seems we have reasonably answered your security questions as well.

Comment: @AskerofCuriousQuestions - If you don’t trust the software you should uninstall it

Comment: @John nothing I didn’t install in there, but I don’t trust every program I use daily to have the ethics of respecting users’ privacy and I suspect that they mine whatever data they can get their hands on

Comment: @Ramhound what I have installed are things I use daily, but I don’t trust them to refrain from collecting data. Plus if it indeed is a malicious program, running its own uninstaller probably won’t uninstall it cleanly either, but that’s beside the question. The main concern is that I suspect some of the programs I use normally and daily may be collecting excessive data irrelevant to them

Comment: You worried they are going to collect the password to your access point?  Don't you think that sort of data collection is low risk?  The individual collecting the data would have to be within a specific distance for it to be used.  Any event this answer's your primary question, can the password be collected.