# How to know if programs are secretly reading saved Wifi passwords on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, permissions, passwords

I need to find out if any program is secretly accessing saved wifi passwords on my Windows 10 computer. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: What makes you concerned this may be happening? Generally, applications will leave network connection duties to the OS. Any application trying to directly access and capture the connection information will only want to do so in order to send that data elsewhere or to "assist" with future connections on a different system. But before you get worried, you need to get us more data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On Windows 10, can programs read saved wifi passwords behind my back?](https://superuser.com/questions/1663220/on-windows-10-can-programs-read-saved-wifi-passwords-behind-my-back)

Comment: @music2myear thank you. I can’t remember what prompted me to be concerned, but the general line of thinking is I have no idea if Windows is protecting saved Wifi passwords from programs that are not part of Windows? Can they just read saved Wifi passwords without the user’s knowledge or consent?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thank you. I think this question is just diving deeper from that. Basically I need to know if my saved wifi passwords can be read, and if so how do i find out if they are indeed being read

Answer (score 1):

In general, rely on the integrity of the applications you've installed (and on keeping your machine physically safe from installation of malware, e.g., while traveling). It is possible for an application, such as Nirsoft's [WiFi Key View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html), to read the cached passwords in Windows. Before installing an application, check it with a few anti-malware tools, such as through [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).

However, *why is this of concern*? Your WiFi password is only useful for a particular router, and simply allows communication. Do you believe someone is obtaining free WiFi that you are subsidizing? Id so, contact your ISP.

Note that the password does not identify the user, and, for most networks, even those with WPA2, is [not impossible to obtain remotely](https://sguru.org/hack-wep-wpa-wpa2-wifi/). For [WPA2-PSK (AES)](https://www.hellotech.com/blog/which-router-security-option-should-you-choose), more often used in enterprise networks, there would be some advantage to a hacker finding the passkey on a machine, though.

The [IoT might have more severe security issues](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203884/risk-of-giving-untrusted-iot-device-access-to-wifi) than Windows, however. If you have smart light bulbs, TV's, smart speakers, door cameras, etc., with the WiFi password, [give thought to securing them](https://www.designrush.com/trends/iot-security-issues).

Comment: Thank you. If a program is trying to read saved wifi passwords, will Windows ask the user for consent or notify, flag or mark the program doing this in any way for us to know? Is there any way for us to find out at all?

Comment: If it needs to run as Administrator, you might need to provide UAC consent... or not, if it's triggered as a scheduled task. However, se edits above.

Comment: Does the access to saved wifi passwords require Admin?

Comment: @AskerofCuriousQuestions - No[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1663220/on-windows-10-can-programs-read-saved-wifi-passwords-behind-my-back/1663222?noredirect=1#comment2549190_1663222)